# Same PyTorch script not running on different machines

Tags: python, pytorch

I have build a network with PyTorch that runs fine on my local machine. Now I wanted to move it to a machine with GPU/CUDA support to train on larger data. But here the training fails. More precisely, the calculation of the loss function fails

In my code, I have something along the line:

```
loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()
....

def train():
    ...
    loss = loss_function(log_probs, target)
    ...
```

On the GPU machine, the script stops at `loss = loss_function(log_probs, target)`. No error, nothing. Just stops. Even if I enforce using the CPU instead of the GPU.

I use the exact same script with exact same training dataset. Using `print` statements, `log_probs` and `target` look the same/similar on both machines. Nothing in this line is `None`. I simply cannot see why the behaviors would differ on the two machines.

Comment: 1. I would check for GPU memory allocation. 
2. If this is not the problem, check the drivers. 
3. A third option might be that the backend of the two pytorch implementations is different. Probably only one of them is using CUDNN.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of [Mo Hossny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7387369/mo-hossny). The problem was indeed different PyTorch versions. The working machine run PyTorch 0.1.12, On the new machine, I naively installed the latest version which is 0.2.0. After explicitly installing the 0.1.12 version on the new machine, the everything worked fine.

Still not very user-friendly that there is no error or any other output that might hint to this issue.